# How to set link url through php?

Tags: php

I have made 14 url links. I have problem that when I press link 2 it returns 1 and all of the remaining links  return decremented to original value. For example when I press 3 it returns 2. When I press 4 it returns 3 and so on. I want to know why is that.
This is code

```
<html>
    <body>
    <head>
        <title>Paging</title>
        <style>

            #numberDiv
            {
                display: inline-block;
                border: 1px solid black;
                width: 35px;
                height: 35px;
                margin-left: 0.01px;
                background-color: aliceblue;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <?php
    if (isset($_GET["id"]))
    {
        $id=$_GET["id"];
        echo $id;
        echo "<br>";
    }
    $a=14;
    $b=1;
    $c=1;
    for ($b = 1; $b <= $a; $b++) {

        ?><a href="zain.php?id=<?php echo $c; ?>" style="text-decoration: none; text-align: center;color: black;font-size: x-large">
        <?php

        $c=$b;
        echo "<div id='numberDiv'>" . $c . "</div>" ?></a><?php
    }

    ?>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Your assignment `$c=$b` is after when you echo the link. Why do you need `$c` anyway?

Comment: Why are you using `$c`? You can assign `$b` instead of `$c`.

Comment: What is the expected behavior?

Comment: **it is returning** What do you mean **it** here . 
`<a href="zain.php?id=<?php echo $c; ?>` 
or
`echo "<div id='numberDiv'>" . $c . "</div>" ` ?

Comment: I need it for some purpose

Comment: it is some part of code

Comment: I want to set url by other variable

Comment: Thanks jereon.. It solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following code. It will work for you

```
<html>
<body>
<head>
    <title>Paging</title>
    <style>

        #numberDiv
        {
            display: inline-block;
            border: 1px solid black;
            width: 35px;
            height: 35px;
            margin-left: 0.01px;
            background-color: aliceblue;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<?php
if (isset($_GET["id"]))
{
    $id=$_GET["id"];
    echo $id;
    echo "<br>";
}
$a=14;
$b=1;
$c=1;
for ($b = 1; $b <= $a; $b++) {
     $c=$b;
    ?><a href="zain.php?id=<?php echo $c; ?>" style="text-decoration: none; text-align: center;color: black;font-size: x-large">
    <?php

    echo "<div id='numberDiv'>" . $c . "</div>" ?></a><?php
}

?>


</body>
</html>
```